# How do I change alpha of an image view multiple times using thread.sleep?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to create an animation for my game. I am trying to make an animation of a coin flip that will stop under certain conditions.

So far I have tried to change an image view multiple times within one method and using thread.sleep to delay the transition between the pictures.

Using 12 different images I am now trying to make it so the alpha of the first image will set to 0 and the second image will set to one, the the second image will set to 0 and the third will set to 1, etc...

The way I am currently trying to do it is by putting images inside of an array of ImageViews and then calling them sequentially.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.coin_flip_screen);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        headsTails[i].animate().alpha(0).setDuration(100);
        headsTails[i+1].animate().alpha(1).setDuration(100);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What issues you have with your code? Why do you insist on using Thread.sleep?

Comment: You should use handlers instead of Thread.sleep();

Comment: Im trying to use thread.sleep so that there is a small gap inbetween eachtime an image is displayed, otherwise the animation will happen in 1000fps, which is obviously way to fast.

Comment: You can still continue the animation with handlers in much more efficient way. Thread.sleep() must be avoided in Android as it cause the whole thread to sleep. P.S. you can not call Thread.sleep() on UIThread.

Comment: What do you mean by handlers? Im really new to android programming so it'd be great if you could give me an example! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final int size = imageView.length;
final int animTime = 300;
final Handler animationHandler = new Handler();
Runnable animationRunnable = new Runnable() {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(i == size-1){
            animationHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            return;
        }
        imageView[i++].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(animTime).start();
        imageView[i].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(animTime).start();
        animationHandler.postDelayed(this, animTime);
    }
};

animationHandler.post(animationRunnable);
```

This code will iterate through all your imageviews in the array and stop itself once all the images are consumed.

Play along with your `animTime` variable until you get the perfect animation effect. Ideally it should be around 300 to 500 ms.

> I will personally not use array of imageviews to create this effect as
>   it will eat up the memory. There are many more efficient ways to do
>   the coin flip animation, which you can google when you get time.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
    headsTails[i].animate().alpha(0).setDuration(100).start();
```

Comment: That makes it fade, which I don't really want. The picture needs to be consistent, like an actual animation. If I set the duration to 1, would that then do the same thing?